# What's the difference between 'working in/from' and 'working at' a coffee shop?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

1. Does *working at a coffee shop* necessarily imply being employed there?
2. Is *working at a coffee shop* never synonymous to *working in/from the coffee shop*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Working from" is the best choice to unambiguously signal that you are not employed by the coffee shop, but just using it as a workspace, and "working for" is an unambiguous way to signal employment.

The other two phrases are most typically used for employment, but could also signal "working from" in certain contexts.